# itertools.combinations_with_replacement() with regard to ordering

Tags: python, python-itertools

I need to produce, given an order and a max, a list of all 'order' length lists with each element in range(max). itertools.combinations_with_replacement() doesn't work because while it does give most, in an example where I want

```
max, order = 3, 2
[(0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (0,3), (1,0), (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,0), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3), (3,0), (3,1), (3,2), (3,3)]
```

the following code shorts me a few elements

```
list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement([x for x in range(max+1)], order))

[(0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (0,3), (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,2), (2,3), (3,3)]
```

specifically I need to know if there is an itertools, or other package that will give me the first list above. i.e. I need both (0,1) and (1,0). or in an order=3 case, (0, 0, 1) (0, 1, 0) and (1, 0, 0) will all need to be included

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
>>> max, order = 3, 2
>>> print(list(itertools.product(range(max + 1), repeat=order)))
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3),
 (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3),
 (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3),
 (3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)]
```

Comment: I think that's the one! Thanks so much! I'll accept your answer once it lets me.